# Выполнение Kernel CUDA длительное время на Win7

Tags: windows, kernel, c, cuda, c++

Пишу программу на CUDA для решения одной NP-полной задачи. Собственно вопрос в чем - если программа выполняется менее чем за 2 сек все ок, если больше то драйвер видеокарты сбрасывает выполнение kernela как я понял. Нагуглил решение - отключил это в настройках теперь кернел работает долго, но комп при этом полностью виснет на время его выполнения, и если  задача считается 10 мин то комп просто висит 10 мин. Как и что добавить в код чтобы кернел не вешал всю систему на время его выполнения?

Win7 x64
GeForce 410M

Comment: А может просто вторую карту стоит добавить?

Comment: Как вариант - да, но я ищу программное решение.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить задачу не в одном кернеле, а в нескольких последовательных.

Comment: И еще. Какой драйвер? У меня раньше, еще во времена CUDA 1, при больших задачах комп тоже вис. В один прекрасный момент при установке нового драйвера все стало работать нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На stackoverflow этот вопрос достаточно хорошо раскрыт: [How do you get around the maximum CUDA run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497685/how-do-you-get-around-the-maximum-cuda-run-time). У меня, например, тоже сразу возникла идея разбить расчёт на некоторые итерации чтобы время от времени расчёты приостанавливались и снова возобновлялись. В любом случае, полезно видеть на экране прогресс расчётов